# Completely destroying/erasing the ozone layer to prevent theoretical ice-age

Tags: science-based

The idea is that the earth is beginning another ice age but humanity doesn't like the idea so they want to make it hotter to avoid it (being well aware of solar radiation).

Could the ozone layer be destroyed with a chemical bomb somehow using something like Chlorofluorocarbons or lots of these bombs, and would it actually raise global temperatures?

What would be the most effective way (to maximize temperature increase) of deploying these bombs in terms of detonation locations around the world i.e. North and South poles or how high would they need to be detonated to affect the ozone layer?

Would it affect satellites?

Would the ozone layer regenerate over time and if so, how fast (considering human emission activity on Earth will be stimulated by the need to follow the night in vehicles to stay alive).

Which also brings me to another question whether night time would actually be a viable option to survive solar radiation with no ozone layer. And if so, how fast would humans have to travel to stay in a survivable level of solar radiation, following the night?

This is all for a film I'm making so if not everything works, please suggest different plot directions or adjustments I can make to help it make scientific sense

Comment: Ignoring the pink elephant in the room, what do you mean with "earth is beginning another ice age"? That isn't really something that happens overnight, it takes thousands of years if it isn't somehow artificially triggered. What causes your ice age and why is it a concern? What's the rush?

Comment: So essentially humans have spent hundreds of years trying to develop an alternative to combat the ice age (I'm still figuring out why they take that long) as the glaciers become more and more of a physical threat to major in fast recourse so scientists are desperate and think of the bomb

Comment: @Raditz_35 the milankovitch cycle is the planetary alignments that control the very longscale climate differentials on Earth. We are technically due to be getting cooler weather and possibly an ice age in the next ~1000 years or so. Human induced warming is actually pushing this temperature decrease down so much that we are still expecting net warmth in the future instead.

Comment: @EveryBitHelps Why did you ping me?

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding THouse! If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. Please note that here we give answer to specific questions. In your I count at least 5 different questions. Please rework it to have 1 question per post.

Comment: Solar radiation would not be deadly without the ozone layer. People can safely travel in daytime, they just must take a little care and not expose the bare skin to direct sunlight for a long time. Both UV-cream and clothing/eye-shades work.

Comment: @Raditz_35 cos you asked about the pink elephant  and what the OP meant by 'beginning the next ice age' :)

Comment: Why try destroying the beneficial ozone layer to get a little more sunlight to fight the coming ice age?  Why not, for example, spread giant black plastic sheets over ice fields to adsorb more solar heat?  Why not have countless millions of eternal flames burning fossil fuels for no other purpose than increase greenhouse gases?  Why not build giant space mirrors to reflect light down on the polar regions?

Answer (score 1):

Like said in the edit's it is better to ask single questions, that being said:

1.Bomb would be possible, CFK + ozone = no ozone so any delivery system would work. However using some form of crop duster flying high in the sky would make more sense since they can more easily cover an area with CFK. The raise of temperature would not be very high imo since the ozone layer mainly blocks UV light and the contribution to temperature of this portion of light is limited. Exact details I would not know.

2.The thickness of the ozone layer varies between location on a planet and the season (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ozone_layer for details). The layer is thickest at the poles so more chemicals would be needed there.

3. Satellites are not in the atmosphere so they won't be affected.
4. Yes it would (again see the wikipedia article for details of the chemical reaction that forms the ozone layer). The time it would take to regenerate depends on a lot of factors that are hard to predict (mostly the conditions regarding winds in the atmosphere) this image shows the healing of the ozone layer on earth (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ozone_depletion#/media/File:Ozone_hole_recovery.jpg).

5.This question is definitely too broad. Keep in mind that UV-radiation can easily be stopped by materials, so the main problems isn't staying alive in the radiation but growing enough plants in UV safe conditions to feed ourselves.
5.5 To always be on the dark side of the earth (so always have night time where you are) you need to do a lap of the earth every day. The size of a lap depends on where you are on earth (distance from the equator).

Comment: If you agree that the question is too broad, why are you answering then?

Comment: What do you mean by: *growing enough plants in UV safe conditions*? I thought plants love UV? For Humans it would probably mean: [*Always wear sunscreen*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sTJ7AzBIJoI)

Comment: @Daniel always were sunscreen and always wear wide brimmed hats.

Comment: plants dont love too much UV see:https://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/Features/UVB/uvb_radiation2.php

Comment: Yeah sunscreen would also work